# In MySQL data is stored in disk or in main memory and how data is access from database

Tags: mysql, database, memory, redis

As we know it is an in-memory database(IMDB) the data is stored in the main memory so my question is

1. In MySQL where the data is stored in the main memory or on the disk?
2. when we access the data from MySQL the data come in the main memory before access or direct access from disk?

Comment: Just out of interest why do you care/what difference will it make to you knowing this?

Comment: #1. Initially - on disk only. After first loading the data is cached in memory until another data eliminates it. #2. If access == read then it is taken from the memory if present in the cache. If the data not present then it is loaded from the disk to the cache, and then is accessed from the cache. Server never accesses the data stored on disk directly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.